# How can I read pdf form fields created by Adobe LiveCycle designer in c# using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, acrobat

I'm trying to read pdf form fields created by Adobe LiveCycle Designer using iTextSharp.  I'm able to read other pdf form fields with this code, but when I'm trying to read the fields using `AcroFields.Item`, it shows `count=0`.

Please suggest how I can solve my problem.  My code is give below:

```
    public string P_InputStream = "~/pdf/test.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath(P_InputStream));


    AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
    try
    {
        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in form.Fields)
            {
                switch (form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key))
                {
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_COMBO:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_RADIOBUTTON:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_NONE:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_PUSHBUTTON:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_SIGNATURE:
                    case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_TEXT:
                        int fileType = form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key);
                        string fieldValue = form.GetField(kvp.Key);
                        string translatedFileName = form.GetTranslatedFieldName(kvp.Key);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of form is it? If you do not know that answer to that question then it's likely your code does not work. You are likely trying to read Acrofields from an XFA form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have different type of form one of them is XFA form.I'm newbie to this.Can you please elaborate this in more detail.?

Comment: There are  different types of forms in PDF. Your code addresses only one, Acroforms. XFA is not addressed by Acrofilelds, you would need to extract the XFA XML from the document and parse the information you want.

Comment: Thanks for detail.Can you please provide me any example or reference ?

Comment: Yes: Its called the PDF Reference, sixth edition
Adobe Portable Document Format, Version 1.7